# Searching/filtering an array

Tags: php, arrays, search, filter, typeahead

I have a question. On my site (Concrete 5 based) I have a block to display a list of icons. I have this array. (The array has many more icons than what I've shown, this is just for an example.)

```
    <?php  $options = array(
    'icon-adjust' => 'Icon Adjust',
    'icon-adjustments' => 'Icon Adjustments',
    'icon-adn' => 'Icon Adn',
    'icon-alarmclock' => 'Icon Alarmclock',
    'icon-align-center' => 'Icon Align-center',
    'icon-align-justify' => 'Icon Align-justify',
    'icon-align-left' => 'Icon Align-left',
    'icon-align-right' => 'Icon Align-right',
    'icon-ambulance' => 'Icon Ambulance',
    'icon-anchor' => 'Icon Anchor',
    'icon-anchor2' => 'Icon Anchor2',
);
?>
```

I want to modify my search box so a user can type in something to filter out results from in the array. (Example: if they search for anchor, they'd see the two icon-anchor fields).

Can anyone help me out with how to go about this?

Here is my code for future reference:

```
    <script>
$('input[name=fromPages]').select2({
    placeholder: "<?=t('Search for a Page')?>",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    width: '100%',
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "<?=$view->action('load_pages')?>",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            var results = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, concretePage) {
                results.push({'id': concretePage.id, 'text': concretePage.name});
            });
            return {
                results: results
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
</script>
```

And for the select box:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->label('fromPages', 'Search for an Icon')?>
    <div>
        <?php echo $form->hidden('fromPages'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a picture: (the top search box would filter results from the opened list)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN1Lm.png

Comment: PROTIP: Tag the question with the *language* you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Check out typeahead.js library, you're not going to be able to accomplish this with just php

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: I forgot to mention I've got select2 implemented. If there's any way to use that, i'd love to find out.

Comment: did you look at the examples for select2? https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: are you just asking how to convert your php into a js object?

Comment: I managed to use https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/working-with-blocks/creating-a-new-block-type/implementing-ajax-and-server-side-requests-in-a-block-add-edit-t/ and got it working properly, but in a different context. That searches all of my pages, but I want it to search my above array. Here's an image of what I'm trying to do http://i.imgur.com/Ksrb7iQ.png?1 The top search bar I want to filter results from the opened bar, which is the array I pasted in the original question